# how to set default faul to CAibri in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

can any body let me know where I can set the default to Calibri in ckeditor in using the later ckeditor package

we have tried in ckedior.js file under content .css

Answer (score 0):

do some research and you will find the answers you are looking for 
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_style